# Why do I get System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: by Post function

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem by saving my data from, in jQuery generated table, to database.
somehow is the length of my sting to long as I understand, somebody knows how can I fix it, without editing database properties, like delete empty spaces or something?

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadWeekData();
});

function loadWeekData() {

    // Append database data here

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/JsonWeekEvents",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (i, val) {
                var trow = $('<tr/>').data("id", val.Id);
                //trow.append('<td>' + val.Id + "&nbsp;" + '</td>');
                trow.append('<td style="padding:5px; width:100px; height:70px"></td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsM" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="monVal" class="desc_NumM">' + val.Monday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsT" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="tueVal" class="desc_NumT">' + val.Tuesday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsW" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="wedVal" class="desc_NumW">' + val.Wednesday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsTr" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="thurVal" class="desc_NumTr">' + val.Thursday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsFr" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="friVal" class="desc_NumF">' + val.Friday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsSt" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="satVal" class="desc_NumSa">' + val.Saturday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                    '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsSu" class="tags" />' +
                    '<input type="button" id="addBtn" class="addEvent" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                    '<div style="text-align:center" id="sunVal" class="desc_NumSu">' + val.Sunday + '</div >' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class="idEvent" />' +
                    '</div >' +
                    '</td>');
                trow.append('<td  style="padding:2px; width:100px; height:70px"><a href="#" rel="events-week-edit" class="edit">Edit Week</a></td>');
                tab.append(trow);
            });

            $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
            $("#weekEvents").html(tab);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
        }
    });
    var tab = $('<table class=MyTable border=1 ></table>');
    var thead = $('<thead></thead>');

    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">FSE' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Monday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Tuesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Wednesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Thursday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Friday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Saturday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Sunday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');

    tab.append(thead);

    tab.on("focus", ".tags", function (e) {
        //var prefix = $('.tags').val();

        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/GetSearchValue",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {

                                label: item.Title + ', ' + item.Description, value: item.Title,

                                Id: item.Id,
                                Title: item.Title,
                                Description: item.Description,
                                Location: item.Location
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Error!" + xhr);
                    }
                });  
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var field_id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent");
                field_id.val(ui.item.Id);
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumM");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumT");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumW");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumTr");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumF");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumSa");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".addEvent", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).closest("div").find(".idEvent").val();
        var field = $(this).closest("div").find(".desc_NumSu");
        var select = $(this).closest("div").find(".tags");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AutoEventDetails",
            data: { id: id },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                var res = $('<p>' + data.Title + '<br/>' + data.Description + '<br/>' + data.Location + '</p>');
                field.html(res);
                select.val('');
            }
        });
    });

    tab.on("click", ".edit", function (e) {

        var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var id = tr.data("id");
        //var divM = $(this).closest("div").find("#monVal");
        var field = $(this).closest("tr").find(".ui-widget");
        var mon = field.find(".desc_NumM");
        var tue = field.find(".desc_NumT");
        var wed = field.find(".desc_NumW");
        var thur = field.find(".desc_NumTr");
        var fri = field.find(".desc_NumF");
        var sat = field.find(".desc_NumSa");
        var sun = field.find(".desc_NumSu");
        var monVal = mon.text();
        var tueVal = tue.text();
        var wedVal = wed.text();
        var thurVal = thur.text();
        var friVal = fri.text();
        var satrVal = sat.text();
        var sunVal = sun.text();
        //var res = field.text();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/UpdateWeek",
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        Monday: monVal,
                        Tuesday: tueVal,
                        Wednesday: wedVal,
                        Thursday: thurVal,
                        Friday: friVal,
                        Saturday: satrVal,
                        Sunday: sunVal
                    },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (data) {

                        alert("Week " + id + " changed!");
                        $('#weekEvents').load(loadWeekData());
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Failed, try again");
                    }
                });
        });
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateWeek(int id, EventsWeek w)
{
        using (WeekEventsDBEntities db = new WeekEventsDBEntities())
        {
            EventsWeek ewupt = db.EventsWeeks.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            ewupt.Monday = w.Monday;
            ewupt.Tuesday = w.Tuesday;
            ewupt.Wednesday = w.Wednesday;
            ewupt.Thursday = w.Thursday;
            ewupt.Friday = w.Friday;
            ewupt.Saturday = w.Saturday;
            ewupt.Sunday = w.Sunday;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

My model (I'm using Entity Framework):

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public partial class EventsWeek
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Monday { get; set; }
        public string Tuesday { get; set; }
        public string Wednesday { get; set; }
        public string Thursday { get; set; }
        public string Friday { get; set; }
        public string Saturday { get; set; }
        public string Sunday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After clicking on "Edit Week" link it goes thru and it looks good but then I get an error in the controller and operation fails.

If somebody can help, would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

w.Monday.Substring(0, 100)

will solve the problem, but not for all fields